# How to verify that pdf is text based using ITextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I need to verify that the pdf report is text based (and not bitmap based; however it could contain some images). I do not need to extract the text, just to verify that it is text based.

Is there a way how to perform such a verification using ITextSharp library?

Thanks in advance,

Stefan

Comment: What do you mean by "text based?" It has at least one extractable character?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure there's necessarily going to be a sharp line delineating the two, especially as bitmapped text and "real" text can coexist. If a PDF contains one page of text followed by a full-page image, what does that count as? What if the image is actually a photo?

Comment: I need the code for an acceptance test. I know what text/data should the pdf contain. The task is to make sure that the pdf report generated from the data is "text based" - meaning it is not just a bitmap inside the pdf, that is actually contains the formated text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for text drawing commands easily enough.  The least work on your part would be to try to extract the text and see if anything is there.  Ideally you'd know some of the text it should contain and search for it.  A single sentence or phrase would be plenty for this sort of testing.

Text extraction with iText is pretty trivial these days.  Lots of examples floating around SO, and the web.

Comment: I know this is a little old, but is there any chance you could post a tiny code example? I'm totally new to iTextSharp and don't even know which object to start with. I will be sure to up-vote the answer.